# How to create a query to join the address fields in 2 tables that are not an exact match

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables with similar data: Office Name, Street Address, City, State, Zip and Phone Number.

I need to write a query that will find the offices and addresses that exist in `Table1` but not in `Table2`. The query criteria is the office name and street address, however the street addresses are not an exact match because of abbreviations (Road vs RD, Street vs ST), spaces, periods, etc.

Is there a way to join the Street Address fields using a `like` statement? For example `Table1` may have My Medical Center as the Office Name with a Street Address of 123 Main ST and `Table2` has My Medical Center as the Office Name with a Street Address of 123 Main Street.

Can I join on the Office Name and the numerical portion (123) of the Street Address only?

Comment: Can you add sample data?

Comment: There is no easy way to do this. You could use a series of replaces for known abbreviations to try to clean the data, and use substrings and casts to compare numerical and varchar, but just the thought of it hurts.

Comment: As my case, I will grather the principal character of address to  generate a string per myself algorithm

Answer (score 0):

The following is my that used in my project

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetAddrMatchedKey] 
(
@ZipCode VARCHAR(15)='',
@FirstName NVARCHAR(50)='',
@LastName NVARCHAR(50)='',
@BusiName NVARCHAR(300)='',
@Address1 NVARCHAR(100)='',
@Address2 NVARCHAR(100)='',
@CountryCode VARCHAR(100)=''
)
 RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Key VARCHAR(50)='',@Name VARCHAR(200),@s VARCHAR(100)




-- 1--6
-- Collection zipcoode
DECLARE @Zip VARCHAR(15)
SET @Zip=replace(replace(@ZipCode,' ',''),'-','') +'      '    
SET @Zip=LEFT( CASE WHEN @CountryCode='US' THEN LEFT(@Zip,5) ELSE  @Zip END,6)
SET @Key=@Key+@Zip


---7--10
--collect name
DECLARE @Vowel VARCHAR(300),@Consonant VARCHAR(300)

SET @Name= UPPER(COALESCE(NULLIF(@LastName,''),NULLIF(@BusiName,''),''))
SET @Name=isnull(dbo.fn_RegExReplace(@Name, '%[^a-Z0-9]%', '',NULL),'')
SET @Key=@Key+LEFT(@Name+' ',1)
IF LEN(@Name)<2
BEGIN
    SET @Key=@Key+'   '
END
ELSE
BEGIN

    SET @Name=SUBSTRING(@Name,2,LEN(@Name)-1)   
    SET @Vowel=dbo.fn_RegExReplace(@Name, '%[^AEIOU]%', '',NULL)
    SET @Consonant=dbo.fn_RegExReplace(@Name, '%[AEIOU]%', '',NULL)

    IF LEN(@Consonant)>=3
    BEGIN
        SET @Key=@Key+LEFT(@Consonant,3)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF len(@Vowel)<3 SET @Key=@Key+'   '
        ELSE

        SET @Key=@Key+left(dbo.fn_RegExReplace(@Name, '%[AEIOU]%', '',len(@Vowel)-(3-LEN(@Consonant))),3)
    END
END
--- 11--13
-- Get three digits number from address
--RETURN @Key
DECLARE @p INT
SET @s=ISNULL(nullif(ltrim(@Address1),''),@Address2)+' '

SET @s= '000'+SUBSTRING(@s, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@s),PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%',@s)-PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@s)+1)
SET @Key=@Key+RIGHT(@s,3)


---- 14--14
SET @Key=@Key+left(ISNULL(upper(@FirstName),'')+' ',1)

-- 15--15
SET @Key=@Key+'1'


RETURN @Key
```

**-- Replace function with RegEx**
use this function to get or remove speical character

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_RegExReplace] 
    (
        @string VARCHAR(MAX),
        @substring VARCHAR(MAX),
        @replacement VARCHAR(MAX),
        @ReplaceCount INT
    )
    RETURNS VARCHAR(max)
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @sRet VARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @iPos INT=1,@Count INT=0
        IF isnull(@ReplaceCount,0)<1 SET @ReplaceCount=len(@string)

        WHILE @iPos>0 AND @Count<@ReplaceCount
        BEGIN
           SET @iPos=PATINDEX(@substring,@string)
            IF @iPos>0
            BEGIN
               SET @Count=@Count+1
               SET @sRet=isnull(@sRet,'')+left(@string,@iPos-1)+@replacement
               SET @string=substring(@string,@iPos+1,CASE WHEN len(@string)<=@iPos THEN LEN(@string) ELSE len(@string)-@iPos END)
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
              SET @iPos=0
              SET @sRet=isnull(@sRet,'')+@string
            END
            IF @Count=@ReplaceCount
            BEGIN
               SET @sRet=isnull(@sRet,'')+@string
            END

        END
        RETURN @sRet

    END


END
```